# Computing covariance of two standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, expected-value

I'm trying to find the covariance $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are both standard normal variables.

If $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\Bbb E[XY]-\Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Y]$, and $\Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Y]=0$ (both standard normal), then $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\Bbb E[XY]$. How do I compute this?

Comment: You need more information.  The covariance of two standard normal random variables could be anywhere from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: How about this: I know $X$ is "almost surely" equal to $Y$. Does that make the covariance $\Bbb E[X^2]$?

Comment: Yes, of course it does.

Comment: Ok, so is the expected value zero? Or how would I compute that if not?

Comment: If $X = Y$ almost surely, i.e. with probability $1$, you can freely interchange $X$ and $Y$ in any expected value computation.  So $E[XY] = E[X^2] = 1$.